# open a url on change of dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

"I need to navigate to a url on change of dropdown such that it would have done in by clicking on a link as `<a href="www.abc.com" target="_blank">`

My dropdown is

```
<select onchange="goTo(this);">
                        <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Back to..</option>
                        <option value="0">Manageassesment
                        </option> <option value="1">Job post
                        </option>
                    </select>
```

goTo function is

```
function goTo(ctrl){
document.location.href = (ctrl.selectedIndex) ? "www.qwe.com":"www.asd.com";
```

}

Now the problem is this goTo opens the url in same window but i want that it should do as it would be doing in clicking on an anchor with target="_blank"

Answer (score 2):

Use **[window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open)** function to pass a target as well.

```
function goTo(ctrl){
window.open((ctrl.selectedIndex) ? "www.qwe.com":"www.asd.com", "_blank");
}
```

Comment: The problem with this in IE is It asks : Internet explorer blocked a pop up - allow or not allow. I dont want this

Comment: Try [this](http://javascript.about.com/library/blblock.htm). Some trickery with resizing the popup and it shouldn't trigger popup blockers

Answer (score 0):

You have to use window.open() like this:

```
function goTo(ctrl){
  window.open((ctrl.selectedIndex) ? "www.qwe.com":"www.asd.com");
}
```

Comment: The problem with this in IE is It asks : Internet explorer blocked a pop up - allow or not allow. I dont want this.

Comment: yes but in this case you open a new task in your browser is different to go only in a link

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this:

```
window.open(url, '_blank');
```